# How do Clojure programmers use Macros?

Tags: clojure

My understanding is [Clojure's homoiconicity](http://clojure.org/reader) exists so as to make writing macros easier.

Based on [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457066/use-of-clojure-macros-for-dsls), it looks like Macros are used sparingly, except for DSLs in which higher-order functions are not to be used.

Could someone share some examples of how macros are used in real-life?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's correct that [homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) makes writing Clojure macros very easy. Basically they enable you to write code that builds whatever code you want, exploiting the "code is data" philosophy of Lisp.

Macros in a homoiconic language are also extremely powerful. There's a fun example presentation I found where they [implement a LINQ-like query syntax in just three lines of Clojure](http://www.slideshare.net/pcalcado/lisp-macros-in-20-minutes-featuring-clojure-presentation).

In general, Clojure macros are potentially useful for many reasons:

- **Control structures** - it's possible to create certain control structures using macros that *can never be represented as functions*. For example, you can't write `if` as a function, because if it was a function then it would have to evaluate all three arguments, whereas with a macro you can make it only evaluate two (the condition value and either the true or false expression)
- **Compile time optimisation** - sometimes you want to optimise your code based on a constant that is known or can be computed at compile time. For example, you could create a "logging" function that logs only if the code was compiled in debug mode, but creates zero overhead in the production application.
- **Code generation / boilerplate elimination** - if you need to produce a lot of very similar code with similar structure, then you can use macros to automatically generate these from a few parameters. If you hate boilerplate, then macros are your friends.
- **Creating new syntax** - if you see the need for a particular piece of syntax that would be useful (perhaps encapsulating a common pattern) then you can create a macro to implement this. Some DSLs for example can be simplified with additional syntax.
- **Creating a new language with entirely new semantics** (Credits to SK-Logic!) theoretically you could even go so far to create a new language using macros, which would effectively compile your new language down into Clojure. The new langauge would not even have to be Lisp-like: it could parse and compile arbitrary strings for example.

One important piece of advice is **only use macros if you need them and functions won't work**. Most problems can be solved with functions. Apart for the fact that macros are overkill for simple cases, functions have some intrinsic advantages: they are more flexible, can be stored in data structures, can be passed as parameters to higher order functions, are a bit easier for people to understand etc.

Comment: You forgot one thing: `creating new semantics`. I.e., building a compiler for an arbitrary complex language on top of a host language. In most cases macros are the only choice for this task, as anything else would be too inefficient.

Comment: Good point SK-Logic! I've added this to the answer but feel free to edit if you have any further ideas / thoughts

Comment: @mikera, thanks. You can even add some examples: Algol running on top of Racket Scheme, and Schelog - an entirely different semantics, but with the same syntax as the host, and even more - embeddable seamlessly into the host language.